# stat_qq_line vanishes when defining ylim

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a QQ-plot for my data, but for some reason my QQ-line just vanishes when I specify limits for the y-axis. Here is a picture of the situation and the code below:
[PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVzLm.png)

```
pqqt <- (ggplot(dataframe_sp500_logreturns_melt, aes(sample = value))+
                 stat_qq(distribution = qt.scaled, dparams = params_t[]) +
                 stat_qq_line(distribution = qt.scaled, dparams = params_t[]) +
                 ### ylim(-0.05,0.05)+
                 labs(x = "Theoretical quantiles (2)", y = '')
)
```

I've marked the ylim in the code with "###". The reason for the limits is to put this QQ-plot besides another QQ-plot with the same limits to compare them.

Comment: In my understanding, you can't limit the plot range inside the endpoints of the line, as the qq-line is defined with two endpoints. Otherwise, the line will be gone.

Comment: But if I do it for distribution = qnorm there is no problem.

Comment: Does it disappear if, in the place of "ylim(-0.05, 0.05)", you use "coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-0.05,0.05))"?

Comment: @Jack 's suggestion should work and here's why: `ylim()` is a wrapper for `scale_y_continuous(limits=...`.  That function limits the axis via *removing datapoints* that are outside the limits and plots only points within the limits.  `coord_cartesian(...` will not remove any datapoints and just affect the window of what you see in the plot.  In this case as also mentioned, your line will have no points to plot with `ylim()`, but will still contain the points to plot with `coord_cartesian()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it with breaks;

```
scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(-0.05,0,0.05))
scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(-4, -2, 0, 2, 4))
```

but with limits, it removes some data points

```
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.05,0.05))
scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(-4, -2, 0, 2, 4))
```

[r](/questions/tagged/r) [statqq](/questions/tagged/statqq) [statqqline](/questions/tagged/statqqline)